# Resetting state of a component in ReactJs by changing its position in the UI tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

**React will keep the state around for as long as you render the same component at the same position**

in this example, I render 2 **Counter** components, by checking the checkbox, I control showing/hiding the first **Counter** component.

```
export default function App() {
  const [showA, setShowA] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
       {showA && <Counter />} 
      <Counter />
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={showA}
          onChange={e => {
            setShowA(e.target.checked)
          }}
        />
        Render the first counter
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

based on the docs, ** React keeps track of which state belongs to which component based on their place in the UI tree. You can control when to preserve state and when to reset it between re-renders.**

so when I hide/then show the first Counter, its state gets reset, the question is, by hiding and showing the first counter, we are changing the position of the second counter, yet its state doesn't get reset, any help why?

I expected that since the position of the 2nd component changes, then its state will reset as well, yet that did not happen

Comment: When the docs say "position" they mean the position in the element tree, not the "visual" position on screen.

Comment: I know, they don't mean the position in the JSX, but by removing the first Counter, the second Counter becomes the first, which is actually changing the position in the tree

Answer (score 0):

According to [Javascript docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND):

> operator returns the value of the first falsy operand encountered when
> evaluating from left to right, or the value of the last operand if
> they are all truthy

I am no expert in Javascript / React JS, but I believe your react UI tree holds values below:

- first position: `false` or `<Counter />`
- second position: always `<Counter />`

Hence, your second `<Counter />`'s state will not reset.